# DRF - overrige Serializer.update to update related set

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to override `update` method of `ModelSerializer` so I can update the related set of objects while updating the instance.

The problem is that `validated_data` doesn't include `ids` of these objects even when I'm passing there to the serializer.

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    subcontracts = validated_data.pop('subcontracts') # THERE ARE NO IDS HERE
    contract = super().update(instance,validated_data)
    instance.subcontracts.exclude(id__in=[x.get('id',None) for x in subcontracts if x is not None]).delete()
    for subcontract in subcontracts:
        _id = subcontract.get('id',None)
        if _id:
            sc = SubContract.objects.get(id=_id)
        else:
            sc = SubContract()
        for attr, value in subcontract.items():
            setattr(sc, attr, value)
            sc.contract = instance
        sc.save()


    return contract
```

Basically, what I want to do:

```
{id:4, some_data..., subcontracts:[{id:1,description:'xxx'},{id:2,description:'yyy'}]}
```

This data would (except updating the instance) delete related `subcontracts` not having id 1 or 2 and update the rest.

Do you know what to do?

Comment: Without the serializer definition and a payload that triggers the problem, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Can you please post the full serializer class with the Meta class? Also, what is the type of the `subcontracts` field in your serializer? Is it another serializer instance or something else?